# Async/Await on appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, async-await, dart-async

When I use async await methods, I get the following error on google dart appengine, how can we use async await on app engine?

> INFO: Creating container... INFO: Container
>   e40102016036bcc2bc36a3b4f5a39c2c427a107e8ead3f86d025cdce950e25af
>   created. DEBUG: Container: e40102016036: Observatory listening on
>   http://a.domain:8181 DEBUG: Container: e40102016036:
>   'package:forcemvc/server/serving_files.dart': error: line 46 pos 71:
>   use flag --enable-async to enable async/await features Future
>   serveFile(HttpRequest request, String root, String fileName) async { ^
>   DEBUG: Automatic cleanup... DEBUG: Cleanup finished. INFO: default:
>   "GET /_ah/health?IsLastSuccessful=no HTTP/1.1" 503 - DEBUG: Health
>   check response [''] and status 503 Service Unavailable for instance 0.
>   DEBUG: Health check state for instance: 0: 3 consecutive UNHEALTHY
>   responses. DEBUG: Performing health check for instance 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `--enable-async` to the `DART_VM_OPTIONS` environment variable.
You can set it using the `app.yaml` file like:

```
env_variables:
  DART_VM_OPTIONS: '--enable-async'
```

You might need to update to the most recent Dart Docker image (for example `google/dart-runtime` - updated 4h ago)

Comment: You're talking about publishing to pub.dartlang.org? If you are starting a new package I think it should be fine. Ensure to have proper `environment:` > `sdk: '>=1.8.0'` setting in your `pubspec.yaml`. You should be aware that several teams can't update to the latest versions immediately because they use dependencies which are not yet updated or politics that doesn't permit it. You'll have to do the estimate yourself about how much effort you might save and how many potential users aren't able to use your package yet and if this pays off.